# Cannot convert string to int32 LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have code like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in tmpDatosModulos.Rows)
                {
                    tmpBSCID += row["ModuloURL"].ToString();
                    tmpBSCID = tmpBSCID.Replace("../BSC/wf_BSC_Reporte.aspx?BSCID=", "");
                }

 bsc = _c.ConfiguracionesBalance.Where(x => x.mdEstatusRegistro && x.sEstatus.Equals("A") && x.ID == int.Parse(tmpBSCID)).ToList();
```

I get error when I debbug it:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

I read another questions about that, and solution explained is to parse outside LINQ expression so I do something like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in tmpDatosModulos.Rows)
                {
                    tmpBSCID += row["ModuloURL"].ToString();
                    tmpBSCID = tmpBSCID.Replace("../BSC/wf_BSC_Reporte.aspx?BSCID=", "");
                }
   tmpBSCID = int.Parse(tmpBSCID);
bsc = _c.ConfiguracionesBalance.Where(x => x.mdEstatusRegistro && x.sEstatus.Equals("A") && x.ID == tmpBSCID).ToList();
```

but I get

> Cannot implicity convert int to string

in this line `tmpBSCID = int.Parse(tmpBSCID);`

It's a little confussing because I'm converting string to int and no viceversa. Regards

Comment: Simply cast in linq : (int)tmpBSCID

Comment: @jdweng `tmpBSCID` is a string

Comment: when you debug the code.. what is the value of `tmpBSCID` are you sure that the values in the row["ModuloURL"].ToString() is a convertible string to int value..? I would not be doing my increments the way you are doing as well ..use the debugger for starters

Comment: in the line `tmpBSCID = int.Parse(tmpBSCID` does not make sense to me. You are actually parsing the string `tmpBSCID` to int and trying to assign it back to string again, is this correct?

Comment: Sergey : Linq will convert a string to an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of type is your variable "tmpBSCID"? From the code you poste seems it's a **string**, and in the part

```
tmpBSCID = int.Parse(tmpBSCID);
```

you are assigning a int field to a string variable. If you need to keep using tmpBSCID, after the parsing method use the "ToString()", otherwise you can create a new int variable (or var).
I would rewrite it as

```
var tmpBSCIDValue =  int.Parse(tmpBSCID);
bsc = _c.ConfiguracionesBalance.Where(x => x.mdEstatusRegistro && x.sEstatus.Equals("A") && x.ID == tmpBSCIDValue).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign a new variable (of type integer) to the result of your parsed string, and applying the integral variable to your LINQ query, i.e.:

```
var myIntegerBSCID = int.Parse(tmpBSCID);
bsc = _c.ConfiguracionesBalance
  .Where(x => x.mdEstatusRegistro && x.sEstatus.Equals("A") && x.ID == myIntegerBSCID)
 .ToList();
```

Other than `dynamic`, C# will not allow you to change the type of an existing variable, i.e.

```
 tmpBSCID = int.Parse(tmpBSCID);
```

can't work, because the LHS type would need to be Integral, whereas the original  RHS type of `tmpBSCID` is of course string.

As an aside, consider using a `StringBuilder` to build up tmpBSCID rather than looping and concatenating strings.

And finally, you might also consider the case where `tmpBSCID` cannot be parsed as an integer. You can use `int.TryParse(out var myIntegerBSCID)` as an alternative - it returns false if the parse fails.

Answer (score 1):

From your code (`+=`) I conclude what you're trying to do is: collect a *list* of ID values from a data table, not just one single ID. So you have to build this list and then use `Contains` in the LINQ query:

```
var idValues = tmpDatosModulos.Rows.Select(row =>
    {
        tmpBSCID = row["ModuloURL"].ToString()
            .Replace("../BSC/wf_BSC_Reporte.aspx?BSCID=", "");
        return int.Parse(tmpBSCID);
    }).ToList();

 bsc = _c.ConfiguracionesBalance
         .Where(x => x.mdEstatusRegistro && x.sEstatus.Equals("A") 
                  && idValues.Contains(x.ID)).ToList();
```

Side note: you seem to be confident that `int.Parse` always succeeds. I'd prefer using `int.TryParse`.

Answer (score 0):

Althoug LINQ does not recognize `int.Parse()` you can do `bsc = _c.ConfiguracionesBalance.Where(x => x.mdEstatusRegistro && x.sEstatus.Equals("A") && x.ID == (int)(tmpBSCID)).ToList();` to force the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your first error, I gather that `_c.ConfiguracionesBalance` is an `IQueryable`.

IQueryables are different that IEnumerables in the fact that an IQueryable doesn't hold the code to create an Enumerator for your sequence. It holds an `Expression` and a `Provider`. The `Provider` knows who should perform the `Expression` (usually an external process like a database). The provide also knows the language this external process speaks (for example SQL). The provider knows how to translate the `Expression` into this language.

As soon as you want to access the first element of the sequence represented by your IQueryable, the IEnumerator for this sequence is fetched from the IQueryable. The expression is sent to the Provider who translates it into the language for the other process and orders this other process to perform the query.

This provider can't translate your own functions into SQL. In fact, although there are a lot of .NET functions that can be translated, there is a [list of supported and not supported LINQ functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities)

In this list you can see that Int32.Parse is not supported. Therefore it was wise to parse locally.

You don't write the type of `tmpBSCID`, but from your statements I gather that it is a string. If you'd written the type, you'd already answered the questioin for yourself:

```
string tmpBSCID += row["ModuloURL"].ToString(); // from your code
tmpBSCID = Int32.Parse(tmpBSCID);
```

And you wonder why the compiler complains that it can't convert the int to a string?